# Does there exist a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the sum over the volumes of every countable covering is infinite but $A$ has finite volume?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

My measure theory material states that the Lebesgue outer measure of a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is at most $\infty$ if for every countable covering $A \subset \bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}C_k$, the sum over the volumes of individual $C_k$ is infinite. Therefore, I am interested in knowing whether it is possible that a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ has a finite Lebesgue outer measure, yet the said sum is infinite for all coverings of $A$?

Comment: Is there any condition on $C_k$? Otherwise, can't you take $C_1 = A$ and $C_k = \emptyset$ for $k > 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the Lebesgue outer measure of $A \subset \mathbf R^n$ is
$$ \lambda_n^*(A) = \inf \left\{ \sum_k \mathrm{vol}(C_k) \mid A \subset \bigcup_k C_k \right\}$$
where the $C_k$ are cubes (although other simple objects work as well). Suppose that $\lambda^*(A) < \infty$. Using the definition of the infimum, there must exist some cover of $A$ satisfying
$$\sum_k \mathrm{vol}(C_k) < \lambda^*(A) + 1  < \infty.$$
Thus if the sum corresponding to every cover is infinite, so is $\lambda^*(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

Working in $\Bbb{R}$, for any $A\subset \Bbb{R}$

$m*(A) =\inf\{\sum_{n} \ell(I_n): A\subset \bigcup_{n} I_n\}$ where $(I_n)$ is any sequence of intervals that cover $A$.

Then clearly $m*(A) \le \sum_{n} \ell(I_n)$

Suppose $m*(A) <\infty$ ,
then given any $\epsilon>0$ , $\exists (I_n) $ with $A\subset \bigcup_{n} I_n$ such that $\sum_{n} \ell(I_n)<m*(A) +\epsilon$

Comment: Conclusion: $m*(A) <\infty$ implies $\exists (I_n) $ with $A\subset \bigcup_n \ell(I_n) $ such that $\sum_n \ell(I_n) <\infty$